# Return windows to original monitors after reconnecting a dock

Tags: display, dock

At work, we have 2 monitors connected to a dock that plugs into the macbook pro via a single usb-c.

Most of the time I'll work on all 3 screens (2Mons + macbook), but when I unplug for a meeting, do some work, and then return, all windows on all workspaces are in the one main monitor.

Is there an automated way to return all windows to the monitor they were displayed in upon re-docking?

note: I have disabled "Displays have separate Spaces" (for convenience)

Comment: I don’t recall whether it dumps them all on the main window or adds new spaces in the background corresponding to each monitor, but as I always worked with displays have separate spaces turned on, I’m not sure how it functions with that setting turned off. (And with my new MacBook that lacks the old Thunderbolt ports I don’t have any way to test it.)

Comment: With Separate Spaces disabled, it dumps them in the remaining Screen for each Space. Occasionally one of my screens glitches & the Mac loses it for a couple of seconds... then I have to go put them all back again, one at a time. Never found anything that could 'remember' the setup.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245884/arrange-different-external-displays-of-same-model-to-different-positions/257864#257864

Comment: Thanks @Allan that's a place to start, but I don't think my employer will want to pay for [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/). I'll wait to see if a free solution comes up.