# Is there a way to automate the movement of application windows to assigned monitors?

Tags: mac, desktop, automation, alfred

So I have a new set up: 2 large screens (top left and top right), my macbook pro (centre), and my ipad (left).

I'm a coder, I like to have my coding environment in the centre, with research on the top left, results (e.g. created webpages) top right. Certain apps like Postman are on the left on the ipad.

Sometimes, as we all do, I reset my computer. When I do this, upon login, all my apps will open on the same screen.

Is there a way (maybe an Alfred script), to move all my applications to the desired monitor (and the desired desktop on that monitor)? It would save SO much time I can't even begin to say.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the application window on the desired screen.  Then right click its Dock icon -> Options -> Assign To -> (select desired target)

These functions are especially helpful if you use Spaces.

Comment: ah sweet, I didn't realise this. I will have to do a test to see what happens on system reset, or if I unplug a monitor and plug it back in. I also didn't realise that each 'Desktop' has a unique number (I thought each Desktop on each monitor would be Desktop 1 Desktop 2.. etc)